# What are the ProGuard rules for Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, proguard

What are the ProGuard rules for these dependencies?

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Firebase uses the [`consumerProguardFiles`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:consumerProguardFiles) feature to automatically include the appropriate ProGuard if you're using Gradle, meaning you don't need to manually include anything.

If you need to manually apply the proguard rules, you can extract the `proguard.txt` file from each AAR file.

Comment: This is  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

Comment: How can I extract the proguard.txt file from each AAR file.

Comment: You're using Gradle, so everything you need is included automatically. There's nothing you need to add.

Comment: AAR files can be opened in any program that can open zip files.

Comment: but I used dex2jar-2.0 to chek the class after the signature,  as an example, if I do not put -keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
} 
the class will convert to a , b and c for google.ads ,correct me If I wrong

Comment: So? Those classes can be renamed safely, otherwise there'd be a -keep in the included ProGuard files.

Comment: I need the  -keep to include in the ProGuard files. for the classes that I mentioned above, I used  [ -keepnames class com.firebase.** { *; }  ] but still the classes for firebase showing like a ,b . any suggestion?

Comment: No, you don't need any additional keep rules. The ones that are required for the app to work are already included. It is 100% totally and completely expected that almost all of the classes appear as a.b.c, etc.

Comment: so I don't need to use -keepnames class com.firebase.** { *; } ?

Comment: No, obviously not. You don't need any additional lines in your ProGuard files if you are using Gradle.

Comment: how to fixe `[R8]: Shaking error: Missing method in com.google.firebase.iid.zzau: void <clinit>()`

Comment: The URL is broken