# com.google.firebase.messaging.zza: can't find referenced class android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in my application.
I added following dependency in Build.gradle and tried to build a release build variant.

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'

**Build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Once I tried to build a 'debug' variant it worked fine and Firebase messaging works without any errors. But when I try to build 'release' built varient it outputs following error.

> Warning:com.google.firebase.messaging.zza: can't find referenced class
>   android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable

Can anyone help me with this. Really appreciate your comments. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538901/7094064

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this progurd rule in

progurd-rules.pro

> -dontwarn com.google.firebase.messaging.**

Answer (score 1):

generate the SHA key in release mode and then add it in the firebase and then again download the json file and replace it with your old one in application.

Comment: How to generate key for release mode?

Comment: check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate/35308827#35308827

Comment: I don't think that 's the case. SHA key is optional for firebase as it says.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the warning comes from  the `progurd-rules.pro`. Use `-dontwarn`  option to ignore it.