# Firebase does not work when proguard/R8 is enabled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, proguard, android-r8

I using `...:firebase-messaging:20.0.1` on android and everthing fine when proguard is disabled. but when proguard enabled app crash with this exception

```java
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind to service appPackageName.AppFirebaseMessagingService@e6f415b with Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=appPackageName }: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:3575)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc.onBind(Unknown Source:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:3559)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

build time output by R8

```
{"kind":"warning","text":"The method android.os.IBinder com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc.onBind(android.content.Intent) does not type check and will be assumed to be unreachable.","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538901/11440180) firebase does not need to add manually proguard rules. but i also added below rules but crash is still happening.

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```

Comment: FYI you're not using the most recent version of FCM. Try upgrading.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Opened http://issuetracker.google.com/158433467 to track this. Which version of Android Studio/AGP are you using?

Comment: @sgjesse iam using Android studio 4.0 on ubuntu gnu/linux. but problem solved with upgrading firebase versions to last version

Comment: Thank you. I have updated and closed https://issuetracker.google.com/158433467.